# Conversion from ReadOnlyObservableCollection to List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a datagrid with grouping and I am trying to style the template to add in some summary about the group.

**IN XAML DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyle**

```
        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,1,0,1" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Items, Converter="{StaticResource summaryConverter}"}" />
        </Grid>
```

**Binding of data grid items source**

```
    PagedCollectionView collection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.ToList<MyClass>());
    collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

**MyClass**

```
    class MyClass {
        public string Name;
        public double Value;
    }
```

I have created a converter to grab the Items of the same group but I am facing problem in converting the object into `List<MyClass>()`. I receive this error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]'.
>   `

**In Converter.cs**

```
    public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object param, CultureInfo culture) {
        var source = (List<MyClass>)values;
    }
```

Does anyone know how should I do the conversion??

Comment: Why do you need a List?

Comment: Because the item source is a list of MyClass and I would like to do the summation of the property `Value` inside the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ.

```
public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object param, CultureInfo culture) {
    var source = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>) values;
    List<MyClass> list = source.OfType<MyClass>().ToList();
    ...
}
```

Comment: these conversion doesn't work. it return  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1[MyClass]'.